# twitter API problem

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am using this to get my latest Tweets

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript"src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=2"></script>
```

so i have to get the latest 2 tweets cause i set the count to 2 , sometimes it returns only 1 why is that ?

Comment: Are you actually using `&amp;` in your url?  If so, you should change it to just `&` for starters;

Comment: @Jeff: Actually URIs should be encoded with `&amp;` if using strict XHTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275150/xhtml-and-ampersand-encoding

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I never thought about it, but this sums it up pretty nicely: http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp

Answer (score 2):

I actually ran into this same problem today it's in the documentation that twitter doesn't return re-tweets in the list for backwards compatibility:

> count.  Optional.  Specifies the
>   number of statuses to retrieve. May
>   not be greater than 200. (Note the the
>   number of statuses returned may be
>   smaller than the requested count as
>   retweets are stripped out of the
>   result set for backwards
>   compatibility.)

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses-user_timeline

That could be what's causing it for you.

Comment: actually sometimes retweets appear and sometimes my tweets doesn`t appear , that`s what make it weird

Comment: Could the difference be re-tweets you do by convention i.e. putting RT in front of the message vs. clicking the re-tweet button?