# Ampersand encoding in url with a HTML style tag

Tags: html, css, ampersand

I have the following HTML style tag

```
<style>
    #loginBackground {
        background-image: url(https://somedomain.com/services/storage?id=89174&amp;type=picture&amp;secret=ucWEYqzpQk8QCaHHp3lfDy5vRrISWwUgzGLnWaDD&amp;timestamp=1478862301);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
    }
</style>
```

Chrome queries this url: `https://somedomain.com/services/storage?id=89174&amp;type=picture&amp;secret=ucWEYqzpQk8QCaHHp3lfDy5vRrISWwUgzGLnWaDD&amp;timestamp=1478862301` without turning `&amp;` in `&` so the image is not displayed correctly.

Document doctype is `<!DOCTYPE html>` so HTML 5.

Everything works fine if I don't encode these ampersands but according to this thread [what's the de facto practice on ampersand encoding in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768391/whats-the-de-facto-practice-on-ampersand-encoding-in-html) all ampersands must be encoded.

I've tried to use `&#38;` instead of `&amp;`, using double or single quotes around the url but nothing works.

Is this a browser bug or in this case ampersand should not be encoded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<style>` (and `<script>`) elements are defined (in HTML 4 terms) as containing CDATA. ([HTML 5 says the same thing](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#script-data-state), but not as clearly).

This means that the normal rules for markup do not apply and entities are not expanded.

If you want an ampersand character inside a `<style>` element then you must use a literal ampersand.

Comment: @arkascha — The OP *observed* that and asked if it was a browser bug or if it shouldn't be encoded. This answer clearly says that it is the behaviour defined in the HTML spec.