# Another ampersand issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have basic html stored in my database, which includes html such as the anchor tag.

I am storing all & in the database as `&#38;`

However, when the data is displayed back on the screen, the anchor tags stop working because the & in the links become `&#38;`.

The problem is, the rest of the content around the anchor tag should remain as `&#38;`

For example

The database content might look like this

```
<p>this is paragraph 1 & this is <a href="http://www.companyname.com/page.php?paragraph=2&sentence=4">paragraph 2</a>.</p>
```

The & in the url becomes `&#38;` which stops the url from working, but at the same time, the & in the

tab any any other tag should remain as `&#38;`

Comment: Both the & in the href and in the <p> should be encoded as &amp; to be valid - http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp

Comment: I don't think that this should stop the URL from "working". It's correct to properly encode HTML entities; people generally don't bother encoding the `&` in URLs in HTML, but they should.

Comment: @Twelve47: That worked.  Thanks.  You should make this your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Twelve47: Aren't `&#38;` and `&amp;` the same entity?

Comment: if the database already contains "valid" html (that is `<p>` and `<a>` and stuff), then why not require `&` to be stored as `&amp;` as well? right now you are storing only partly valid html, since e.g. `& this…` is not a valid html entity

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: For some reason, for me anyway, the urls stop working.

Comment: @Twelve47: Also, that page is not quite accurate; replacing `&copy` with the copyright symbol is not "correct" at all (missing semicolon), though browsers _will_ do it anyway.

Comment: You shouldn't store encoded HTML in your database. Encoding should be done on output. Maybe next time you want to output the HTML to an API or via Javascript > you don't want HTML encoding then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the & in the href and in the `<p>` should be encoded as `&amp;` to be valid

Source: http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

I assume you are storing the url separately in db.

See also: http://pl.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php

Comment: No, the urls are in the content, i.e. i have a content column in the database, and all text and urls within the text go into that single column for content.  Just like your answer, the links are within the sentences.

Comment: Than it becomes quite tricky. I think your WYSIWYG editor makes the conversion before putting into db. You can use some kind of regexp query to extract the url and change it. Or just use str_replace to change `&#38;` into `&`

Comment: They shouldn't be decoded. Entities *should* be encoded in HTML.

Comment: But shouldn`t this be encoded as `&amp;` not as `&#38;` ? see: http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp

Answer (score 0):

The URL should still "work".

Although common convention is not to bother, HTML entities such as ampersands [should always be encoded](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RdrG1aJZ4lgC&pg=PA318&lpg=PA318&dq=entity%2038%20ampersand%20href&source=bl&ots=k6_Ep11kWE&sig=6CwGJcBlNE3NLfDSy6TZO82kXjU&hl=en&ei=E7auTcKEIIjbsga__tThDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=entity%2038%20ampersand%20href&f=false) like `&amp;` or `&#38;` — you're already doing the latter, so the resulting URL should be valid.

e.g. `<a href="page.php?a=1&amp;a=2">link</a>` and `<a href="page.php?a=1&#38;a=2">link</a>` both present an anchor tag linking to the URI `page.php?a=1&a=2`.

---

**Update** Ah, apparently in some browsers the hash in `&#38;` [is seen as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275150/xhtml-and-ampersand-encoding/280408#280408) ending the URL.

What a mess! Use `&amp;` instead of `&#38;` ... [or, ideally, `%26`](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N7150.html#d9565e1389).