# ASP.NET MVC Javascript Redirect encoding issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to use Razor to inject a URL into a Javascript variable, and then redirect the browser to that URL.  I need to do it this way as my application is fully AJAX based and I'm redirecting to a Facebook Authentication page.

The view that performs the client-side redirect looks like this:

```
@model Site.Core.ViewModels.Auth.FacebookCanvasLoginModel

<script type="text/javascript">
    var redirectUrl = '@(Model.FacebookLoginUrl)';

    window.top.location.href = redirectUrl;
</script>
```

The value of Model.FacebookLogin URL is generated by the Url.Action() helper in MVC.

the problem is that the location that is actually redirected to is:

```
http://dev.mydomain.net/Auth/RequestPermission?permissions=read_stream%2Cuser_photos&amp;redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mydomain.net%2Fnewsfeed%3F_%3D1328276903643
```

which contains `&amp;redirectUrl=` instead of `&redirectUrl=`

How do I pass this URL to window.location.href without the `&` being encoded to `&amp;` whilst maintaining the redirectUrl as an encoded URL string?

Comment: What's the code within the `FacebookLoginUrl` method? What's it returning? It seems like this method is the issue and is adding the encoding when it shouldn't. (By the way, for argument's sake, having `<a href="http://site.com/?foo&amp;bar">` with the `&amp;` is the [proper way of generating a URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275150/xhtml-and-ampersand-encoding).)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to get the Raw value so that it doesn't html encode the value.

```
@Html.Raw(Model.FacebookLoginUrl)
```

You are putting it inside javascript, and you'll want to escape anything that could goof up your javascript.  So try this:

```
var redirectUrl = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.FacebookLoginUrl))
```

For your reference: [Json class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538018%28v=vs.99%29.aspx)

Comment: Legend! Thank you!!  Happy to have bumped you over 1000 points - I've been stuck on this for hours :-)