# javascript url help in sending multiple values with url..

Tags: php, javascript

```
"sample1.php?q="+str
```

This code is for sending single parameter i need to send multiple variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HTML:

```
"sample1.php?q=" + str + "&otherParam=" + other;
```

For XHTML/XML:

```
"sample1.php?q=" + str + "%26otherParam=" + other;
```

Comment: "&amp;" is for showing the ampersand in html text, not for JS

Comment: @mplungjan No, that is incorrect.  &amp; is HTML encoded entity for "&".  The correct URI encoding is %26.  Passing "&amp;" into a URI creates the parameter name "amp;otherParam" if not decoded by HTML first.

Comment: Not convinced... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275150/xhtml-and-ampersand-encoding

Comment: @mplungjan  You missed a key statement in the winning answer of that stackoverflow question: _The encoding of & as &amp; is required in HTML, not in the link._ This question here is not about HTML.  This is a JavaScript question.

Answer (score 0):

Define "multiple values". If you mean more than one variable, you can do something like:

```
$url = "sample1.php?q=".$str."&second=".$str2;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<script>
function make_full_url(Page_URL,Params) {
  Page_URL += "?";
  for Key in Params 
    Page_URL += Key+"="+Params[Key]+"&";
  return Page_URL;
}

//test
Page_URL = "sample1.php";
Params = new Array();
Params["q"] = Str;
Params["something"] = "something";

Full_URL = make_full_url(Page_URL,Params);
</script>
```

Comment: i just wannat to send three variables so it is like that?
'sample1.php?q='+str'&a='+a'&b='+b'

Comment: URL = "sample1.php?q="+str+  "&a="+a+  "&b="+b;

Answer (score 0):

i hope i understand you correct... make a array with your values and loop over the key values to concat your url string

```
$values = array('q' => $str, 'val2' => $val2);
$url = 'sample1.php';
$pos = 0;
foreach($values as $key => $value) {
    $url .= ($pos>0 ? '&' : '?').$key.'='.urlencode($value);
    $pos++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a url object for this and use the class methods:

```js
const myURL = new URL('https://www.example.com');

myURL.searchParams.set('fooName', 'fooValue');

console.log(myURL);

// Output = https://www.example.com/?fooName='fooValue'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).