# ASP.NET &amp parameters

Tags: asp.net, url-parameters

I have an ASP.NET page (handler) that works when called using &. However, a third party page which uses my page converts the & to "&" (ampersterand, amp;) and the page throws "Parameter is not valid." error.

I have read that parameters should be encoded with & but it seems to be causing my page to error.

.NET is converting that to ampsterstand,amp, %3

---

Here is more info on the problem

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/06/05/why-is-asp-net-encoding-amp-s-in-script-urls-a-tale-of-looking-at-entirely-the-wrong-place-for-a-cause-to-a-non-existing-bug.aspx

My problem is that I'm trying to use Facebook which is converting the & to the "and amp" form and I believe that it is causing my code not to work.

This is actually the answer. Facebook was displaying the link with the encoded & which .NET will not accept. However, it was using the unencoded form. The problem was that it couldn't pull from HTTPS protocol.

Basically, AMPSTERSTAND non encoded is required as the parameter deliminator.

Comment: `page converts the & to & ...` so it leaves it the same?

Comment: Absolutely not.. it doesn't work. If I try to call the page with & then it works whereas if I try to call the page with ampsterand, amp, semicolon then it fails with "parameter is not valid."

Comment: So you're saying this is happening in your query string?

Comment: Are you familiar with HTML encoding vs Url encoding? If not, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275150/xhtml-and-ampersand-encoding