# XHTML Validation Fatal Error (equal sign)

Tags: validation, xhtml, equals

I've got an XHTML which contains a stylesheet link but does not work t all, because the Validator says this:

> Fatal Error: required character (found =) (expected ;)
>
> At line 10, column 69
>
> =Raleway&subset=latin-ext' rel

This works fine in HTML5.  What should I do?

this is that part of my code:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&subset=latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></link>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XHTML and & (Ampersand) encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275150/xhtml-and-ampersand-encoding)

Comment: The `&amp;` is invalid; use `&#38;` to resolve this issue. Here is a great site for Unicode character encodings: http://unicode-table.com/en/

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should use the htmlentity `&amp;` for the sign "&"

I validated the following code with no errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>some text</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Regards